# Changing my chapter heading style and would like to add some text below the heading and before starting the content

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, thesis, chapter-page

Currently, my PhD thesis chapter heading looks like [image: this]

But I would like to make it like [image: this] or something stylish, but I have to write some text between the chapter name and the starting actual content of the chapter.

Could anyone tell me how to do that, i.e to chapter heading style I would like to add some text below the heading before starting the actual content of the chapter. Thanks for helping.

I am using the following environment

```
\documentclass[thesis,a4paper,11pt]{ucdThesis}
\setlength{\topskip}{10mm}
\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{relsize}                
\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlist[itemize]{align=parleft,left=0pt..1.3em}
\setlist{labelwidth=\widthof{0.},leftmargin={\labelwidth+\labelsep},rightmargin=\leftmargin}
\SetNlSty{}{}{.}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false}

\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
\raggedbottom
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{2pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{2pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\parindent0mm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{\rule{.4\textwidth}{4\baselineskip}}
\setlength{\headheight}{27.23802pt}
\makeatletter
\definecolor{oiGB}{rgb}{.01,.01,.01}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0, 128, 128}
\refstepcounter{mybibcounter}\themybibcounter. }
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{#1}}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=myblue,urlcolor=myblue,citecolor=myblue,}
\newcommand{\eqnumcolor}{\color{myblue}}
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{myblue}(#1)}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\myatop[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{\textit{\leftmark}}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\addToPDFBookmarks{0}{Front Matter}{rootNode}
\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Title}{a}
\makeTitlePage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\makeCopyrightPage
\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Collaborations}{a}
\include{collaborations} 
\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Dedication}{b}
\include{dedication} 
\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Acknowledgements}{c}
\include{acknowledgements}
\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{Abstract}{d}
\include{abstract}

\addToPDFBookmarks{1}{List of Publications}{e}
\include{publications}

\addToPDFBookmarks{0}{Table of Contents}{f}
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor={oiGB}}
\tableofcontents 
}
\addToTOC{List of Tables}
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor={oiGB}}
\listoftables 
}
\addToTOC{List of Figures}
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor={oiGB}}
\listoffigures
}
\addToPDFBookmarks{0}{Nomenclature}{g}
\cleardoublepage
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
\include{chapter7}
\include{chapter8}
\include{chapter9}
\include{chapter10}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Thesis}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Huge}{{\thechapter}}{1em}{}
\newcommand{\chapterwithdesc}[2]{\chapter{#1}\hrule\vspace{1em}\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}\bfseries#2\end{minipage}\end{center}\hrule\vspace{4em}}

\begin{document}

\chapterwithdesc{Chapter name}{Summary of chapter goes here. \blindtext}

Chapter content. \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

### Edit

A more fancy solution based on `fncychap` package.

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\newcommand{\chapterwithdesc}[2]{\chapter{#1}\hrule\vspace{1em}\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}\bfseries#2\end{minipage}\end{center}\hrule\vspace{4em}}

\begin{document}

\chapterwithdesc{Chapter name}{Summary of chapter goes here. \blindtext}

Chapter content. \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your answer, I like the second one, I am not getting the two borderlines when I put your code into my tex file. and is there any way to change the colour grey? Is there any way to change the position of the chapter number? Currently it is touching the grey box which I do not like. Thank you

Comment: @Marso, you can look at the [documentation](https://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fncychap/fncychap.pdf) of `fncychap` package for more styles and defining custom styles. I am not proficient with it, other questions on tex.sx might help. Regarding the borderlines, can you give the complete code? I have also noticed that you use a custom class, which may perhaps be redefining some things.

Comment: OK Thank you very much